# Wrong solution for $\int \frac{1 - e^x}{e^x}\, dx$

Tags: calculus

The solution book gives this as an answer:

$$\int \frac{1-e^x}{e^x}dx = \int \frac{1}{e^x}-\frac{e^x}{e^x}dx = -e^{-x} + C$$

I would think it would be solved this way:

$$\int \frac{1-e^x}{e^x} dx = \int \frac{1}{e^x} -1 \; dx = -e^{-x}-x + C$$

Comment: You'd be right: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+%281-Exp[x]%29%2FExp[x]

Comment: Yes, the solution given in the book is wrong.

Comment: Apparently this is a typo in the book. You should email the authors. Most authors would be happy to catch typos.

Comment: @J.D. This is book was to be a brief review of calculus and in every section there is a problem that either can't be solved with basic methods described like the integral of sin(x^2), or the solutions given are just wrong.  I am getting good at finding these errors, I might just do this for a job one day. I bought a terrible book to review, but there are not many to choose from around here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct.

But, remember, you can always check your answer when finding an antiderivative:

We have:
$$
{d\over dx} (-e^{-x}+C)=e^{-x}\ne e^{-x}-1={1-e^x\over e^x};
$$
so the book is wrong.

However:

$$
{d\over dx} (-e^{-x}-x+C)=e^{-x}-1 = {1-e^x\over e^x};
$$
so, you are right.

Comment: Yes, you can always check your answer by taking the derivative!  This is a very important point.

Comment: Yes, I know that; however, thought that maybe I was missing something.

Comment: @David Mitra thanks for giving it a better title.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see if you been right in solving your integral is to derive both sides.

As we can see, the books answer:

$$\frac{{d}(-e^{-x}+C)}{dx}\neq \frac{ d\{{\int \frac{1}{e^x}-\frac{e^x}{e^x}dx}\}}{dx} $$